# PuTTY broken characters...(using Ubuntu Desktop 11.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 Desktop version on the host computer.

Is the below a problem with PuTTY, Ubuntu, or my client laptop? (which is...'ancient')

[image: Screenshot]

Additionally, is there any way to fix this 'Chinese letters' problem?

I think Ubuntu's localization language is English.

*PS. Yes, I know 'why' is not a proper Ubuntu command.*

Answer (score 0):

I guess those characters are not present in the font available to Putty.

You can check this by using `ls > ls.out; vim -R ls.out` and using vim's `ga` command to view the hexadecimal code-point number for the problematic character. Then check if the font used by Putty contains a glyph for that code point.